# Re-initialize view controller, or create separate view controllers for image capturing process?

Tags: objective-c

I have created a custom camera overlay to capture an item, but my app requires that I go through the capturing process twice, so basically, once the user has taken the picture of the front of an item, they need to take the picture of the back of that same item, back to back. At the moment I am re-initializing the same view controller after the first picture has been taken, but I have read that it would be better practice to create a separate view controllers for each "step".

Which would be the better option, separate view controllers, or one view controller that gets re-used, as and when is needed?

I am quite new to Objective-C, so I am not sure if I have phrased everything correctly, I hope that I was able to adequately convey my problem.